# .docx change font type and size for all document on php

Tags: php, simplexml, docx

I need to count pages on .docx
It's simple to do this with following function:

```
function getNumPages($filename)
{
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  if($zip->open($filename) === true)
  {  
    if(($index = $zip->locateName('docProps/app.xml')) !== false)
    {
      $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
      $zip->close();
      $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
      return $xml->Pages;
    }
    $zip->close();
  }
  return false;
}
```

But first I need to change font type and size of all document. How to do this? Thank you.

Comment: on linux? how to do this?

Comment: If on Linux, then use LibreOffice and UNO

Comment: where can I read more about how to use LibreOffice and UNO?

Comment: http://api.libreoffice.org/ and https://github.com/adjohu/puno

Comment: any ideas without installing LibreOffice and UNO, just using PHP and simplexml?

Comment: Basically it's impossible...... you need something (eg MS Office via COM or Libre/OpenOffice via UNO) that's capable of simulating the rendering the pages with all the styling applied so that they can be counted